# Attempt at showing in a natural deduction style the structure of a proof of " a totally ordered set contains at most one maximal element".

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

If the following  proof attempt  were complete, would it be rigorous enough ? Are there mistakes in this proof regarding logic/mathematics?

- at lines 2 and 4 it it correct to use the same variable x ?
- at line 11 , is it correct to say that I use CP ( conditional proof", or should I say that I use negation introduction ?
- is it acceptable to keep the variable S when I generalize at line 15?

How should it be completed ( what are the missing statements and the missing reasons)?

This proof is atttempted as an exercice in logic. It is not meant to have any mathematical interest.

[image]

Comment: Personally I think you don't need to argue by contradiction here.  If $m$ and $n$ are both maximal elements, then $m>n$ is false and $n>m$ is also false.  But, $m$ and $n$ are comparable since $S$ is totally ordered.  The only remaining possibility is that $m=n$.

Comment: @ChocolateAndCheese. Thanks. That would make the proof more efficient and elegant.

Comment: There are tools (online and otherwise), e.g. https://proofs.openlogicproject.org/, to build and mechanically check natural deduction proofs. Of course, you would need to at least partially formalize your statements, but that probably isn't a terrible thing either. Since your goal seems to be to become familiar with formal logic, then you can just pick things that are easy to formalize or work in terms of abstract predicates.

Comment: As some advice, I would recommend avoiding using proof by contradiction (or its equivalents) except as a last resort. Proofs that don't (indirectly) rely on proof by contradiction are called constructive proofs and they are usually more intuitive/informative. It's also helpful to have a feel for what is and is not constructively provable. To that end, it is useful to formulate things in positive ways. Maximal elements being unique means if you have two maximal elements then they are equal. We can formulate "maximal" in a more positive way as "$m$ is maximal iff $\forall x.m\leq x\to m=x$".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for contradiction proofs here: the statement to be shown is (for unicity) if $m$ and $n$ are both maximal, $m=n$.

If $m$ and $n$ are both maximal (assumption), then by being a total order (so we apply an axiom) , $m \le n$ or $n \le m$ holds (I omit the $m=n$ case which is covered by both anyway, it will follow anyway).

If $m \le n$ then maximality of $m$ implies $m=n$, and

if $n \le m$ then maximality of $n$ implies $n=m$ too

(here I use the "positive version" of maximality):

$$m \text{ is maximal } \iff \forall x: (x \ge m) \implies (x=m)$$

As both options yield the conclusion $m=n$, $m=n$ follows (a standard natural deduction rule in most systems) and unicity has been shown.